# Returning associations for specific model when there is a polymorphic association in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic association in a Rails 3 app where a `User` may favorite objects of various classes.

```
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :favoriteable, :polymorphic => true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites, :as => :favoriteable
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites, :as => :favoriteable
end
```

I would like to be able return a list of just a `User`'s `favorite_images` for example.

```
user.favorite_images #returns a list of the images associated with the user via :favoritable
```

I'm guessing there is a straightforward way of doing this but I haven't been able to figure it out. Let me know if you need anymore info.

Thanks!

===edit====
I know that I could retrieve what I am looking for via

```
favorite_images = user.favorites.collect{|f| if f.favoriteable_type=='Image'; f.favoriteable; end}
```

I could define an instance method for the `User` class and put that inside. I was wondering if there is a way to do it as some sort of `has_many` association. Really just because going forward it would be easier to have all that in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you created the table for `Favorite` you created a couple of columns `favoriteable_id` and `favoriteable_type` and you can use this information to restrict your query.

If you do `user.favorites` you will get all of the favorites and to restrict them to say just the images then you can do `user.favorites.where(favoriteable_type: 'image')` but that just gives you the favorite records and it sounds like you want the actual images. To get those you can do it by then mapping and pulling the favoriteable out. You'll likely want to include it in the query though so you don't hit the database so much. I would also make this a method on `User`.

```
def favorite_images
  favorites.includes(:favoriteable).where(favoriteable_type: 'Image').map(&:favoriteable)
end
```

Comment: i think this is probably how i'll have to do it. i was just hoping for a way to have it listed up with the rest of the associations in my model but functionally this will work.  thanks.